# Drools - check if argument is null before calling query

Tags: drools, rules

Inside the drools rule file, I'm trying to match the request object against inserted facts using a query (backward chaining). How do I check for null for the request object attribute? If the attribute is not null, I want to pass it to the query. If the attribute is null, I want to keep it unbound so that it will match all results. Since there are many request attributes, I'm looking for a generic solution instead of different rules for each attribute.

To give an example, lets assume I have two attributes currency and country in the goal: Goal() object and I want to call the query `isMatching(String country,String currency)`

if goal.getCountry() and goal.getCurrency() is not null, I want to call isMatching with goal.getCountry()and goal.getCurrency().

```
isMatching(goal.getCountry(),goal.getCurrency())
```

if goal.getCountry() is null and goal.getCurrency() is not null, I want to call isMatching with unbound variable country and goal.getCurrency()

```
isMatching(country,goal.getCurrency())
```

if goal.getCountry() is not null and goal.getCurrency() is null, I want to call isMatching with goal.getCountry() and unbound variable currency

```
isMatching(goal.getCountry(),currency)
```

if both goal.getCountry() and goal.getCurrency() are null, I want to call isMatching with unbound variable country and currency

```
isMatching(country,currency)
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to have a separate rule for each combination.

```
rule "both country and currency"
when
  Goal( $country: country != null, $currency: currency != null )
  $isMatching: Boolean() from isMatching( $country, $currency )
then
  // 
end
```

Not sure what you're referring to as an "unbound" variable in your question for your other use cases.

If you insist on not following best practices and try to kludge all of this into a single rule, you could either do your null check on the right hand side, or possibly abuse [conditional and named consequences](https://docs.drools.org/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#drl-rules-THEN-advanced-con_drl-rules) to do this. Doing it in the rule consequences ("then") will cause you to lose all of the performance optimization done by the Drools engine, which is done on the left hand side only.

---

Alternatively you could just update the query to handle the null case.

```
query isMatching( String $country, String $currency) {
  $country := String( this == null )
  or
  $currency := String( this == null )
  or
  ( actual implementation )
}

rule "example"
when
  Goal( $country: country, $currency: currency )
  isMatching( $country, $currency )
then 
  // ...
end
```

Actual implementation may vary; I have no idea how you'd implement a currency <-> country check.

Comment: My question was about backward chaining. 

A query with one or more unbound arguments returns all undefined (unbound) items within a defined (bound) argument of the query. If all arguments in a query are unbound, then the query returns all items within the scope of the query.

Comment: So basically a 'null' since we don't have a Javascript-like 'undefined' state, yeah?